# Outdated link in syntax highlighting help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, broken-link

Not exactly a *broken* link, but:

The help center page on [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) contains a link to [one of the supported prettify language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970).

The details in this answer have been removed and the link should be updated to point to: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)